# How to reload a @Value property from application.properties in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `spring-boot` application. Under the run folder, there is an additional config file:

`dir/config/application.properties`

When the applications starts, it uses the values from the file and injects them into:

```
@Value("${my.property}")
private String prop;
```

Question: how can I trigger a reload of those `@Value` properties?
I want to be able to change the `application.properties` configuration during runtime, and have the `@Value` fields updated (maybe trigger that update by calling a `/reload` servlet inside the app).

But how?

Comment: Have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919270/set-override-spring-spring-boot-properties-at-runtime?

Comment: `spring-cloud` with `@RefreshScope` on the `@Service` and running POST requests on `localhost:8080/my-app/refresh` on a property change solved it.

Comment: Basically you don't 'reload' values wired with @Value. But you can obtain a similar behavior using something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648630/39998

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmorgan/ReloadablePropertiesAnnotation

Answer (score 7):

Use the below bean to reload config.properties every 1 second.

```
@Component
public class PropertyLoader {

    @Autowired
    private StandardEnvironment environment;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
    public void reload() throws IOException {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        PropertySource<?> resourcePropertySource = propertySources.get("class path resource [config.properties]");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        propertySources.replace("class path resource [config.properties]", new PropertiesPropertySource("class path resource [config.properties]", properties));
    }
}
```

Your main config will look something like :

```
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:/config.properties")
public class HelloWorldConfig {
}
```

The instead of using @Value, each time you wanted the latest property you would use

```
environment.get("my.property");
```

**Note**

Although the config.properties in the example is taken from the classpath, it can still be an external file which has been added to the classpath.

Comment: I've derived code from your answer into something a little more general. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648630/39998

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about making @Value have new properties.  I would expect that there must be a way for a prototype bean to be reloaded with new properties.  I would be shocked if there was not.