# Is it possible to change at runtime a specific value inside a property.file in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot, properties

I'm developing an API which will connect with several endpoints. The uri for each endpoint is something like this:

```
rest/services/General/directory1/MapServer/export
rest/services/General/directory2/MapServer/export
rest/services/General/directory3/MapServer/export
rest/services/General/directory4/MapServer/export
```

and so on...

I don't know if it's possible, but would like to have something like this instead:

```
rest/services/General/${value}/MapServer/export
```

and then on my code just call the endpoint above injecting the specific directory that I want on **${value}**

Is it possible? Don't know what I'm missing as I googled but couldn't find anything related.

Cheers

Comment: You can use maven profiles. set maven property on profile generate different flover. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by means of Spring Cloud Config.

> Spring Cloud Config provides server and client-side support for
>   externalized configuration in a distributed system. With the Config
>   Server you have a central place to manage external properties for
>   applications across all environments. The concepts on both client and
>   server map identically to the Spring Environment and PropertySource
>   abstractions, so they fit very well with Spring applications, but can
>   be used with any application running in any language. As an
>   application moves through the deployment pipeline from dev to test and
>   into production you can manage the configuration between those
>   environments and be certain that applications have everything they
>   need to run when they migrate. The default implementation of the
>   server storage backend uses git so it easily supports labelled
>   versions of configuration environments, as well as being accessible to
>   a wide range of tooling for managing the content. It is easy to add
>   alternative implementations and plug them in with Spring
>   configuration.

For more details, kindly go through spring documentation  [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config).

Comment: cheers for the reply. Will have a look now, but I would like to use just spring boot if possible as I'm working for a client and the project was handled to me by them, and all the dependencies of the project it's stored by them, meaning I don't have direct access to them. They want like that, so if possible I was looking for just spring boot, but will have a look and see if I can do it. Cheers for taking the time to help :)

Comment: May be this post is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287771/how-to-reload-a-value-property-from-application-properties-in-spring

Comment: Thanks mate for helping out, but I just decided to use the simplest approach: string.replace(). Just thought would be much of trouble to implement this using spring cloud.

Comment: For scenario ahead of you, what you said seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using the simplest approach possible. In my code I used the string.replace() method. Was looking for something more robust, but as it was taking lots of time to sort it out how to do it, I decided to go with the string.replace method.