# externalize configuration in spring boot aws

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

we have a usecase where we have to externalize configuration properties for microservices(spring boot app) and we must be able to change it on the fly - means without restart.

I know about spring config server can help here but was checking if we already have some solution like this on AWS.

Please suggest.

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287771/how-to-reload-a-value-property-from-application-properties-in-spring/40288822#40288822)

Comment: In this case properties file is in classpath and when you build jar file then how can you change values. Sorry I didn't get that.

Comment: Just add the config.properties to the start of the classpath. Classpath can include external files.