# How to override a variable in Spring Boot properties file

Tags: spring-boot

I have an existing properties file like below

```
csv.requireresync=true
```

There are two actions in the system that will get and set value to it.

1. Every 5 minutes there will a process that will set the `csv.requireresync` to false.
2. Every 2 weeks there will be a process that will set the `csv.requireresync` to true.

I tried to do the above using `@Component` but not working

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "csv")
public class ResyncConfig {

    private boolean requireresync;

    public void setRequireresync(boolean requireresync) {
        this.requireresync = requireresync;
    }

    public boolean isRequireresync() {
        return requireresync;
    }
}
```

*The idea is when the I call `setRequireresync` to true the value must reflect in the application.properties file.*

Is it possible achieve what I want ? or do I need a extra configuration file for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set/override Spring / Spring Boot properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919270/set-override-spring-spring-boot-properties-at-runtime)

Comment: You do know that if you simply set that property in `ResyncConfig` it will be shared accross whole application? CSV is just for bootstraping initial values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set required values directly to `ResyncConfig` isntance. It is shared across application (if not using Scopes its singleton) and any changes made to it will be in effect. File is only for bootstraping config class with initial settings.

Comment: If the application restarted. The new value should not be lost. Lets say the property in the file originally set to true. Then I set it to false through code. Will the properties file now updated to false ?

Comment: How to change settings on runtime? - like I described above. How to persist it between restarts? - Update config file.