# How do I change the values of application.yaml at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How do I change the values of application.yaml at runtime
e.g I have a server address property that I would like to change at runtime

server:
    address: 192.168.1.100

Comment: Ideally you might have a config server who provides all configs, you can take a look https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set/override Spring / Spring Boot properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919270/set-override-spring-spring-boot-properties-at-runtime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is a spring application, if so you can use the jvm arguments (-D) to override the values from application.yaml file. 
e.g 
application.yaml

```
server:
  address: 192.168.0.1
```

cmd line

```
java -jar -Dserver.address=10.10.0.1
```

Comment: Thats not really runtime :D thats property on startup!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override many properties you can also use a separate file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name = "default", value = "classpath:default.yaml"),
        @PropertySource(name = "external", value = "file:${custom.properties:}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class BootApplication { ... }
```

And launch like

```
java -jar -Dcustom.properties=/path/to/custom.yaml
```

Where `custom.yaml` contains

```
server: 
   address: 10.10.10.100
   port: 8888
   etc: blabla
   ...
```